# how to get first session to equal 1?

Tags: php

Below I have a line of code where it states which Session a user is currently on out of the number of Total Sessions.

```
<h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

So for example the line could read this:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 3 OF 3
```

Now the problem I have is that lets say I want 3 Sessions, It should read like this:

First time user opens page: `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 1 OF 3`

But instead it is reading like this: `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 3 OF 3`

Same if lets say I want 7 Sessions, for first session it should be: `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 1 OF 7` but instead it is reading like this: `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: SESSION (AAA) 7 OF 7.`

So my question is that how can I get the first session to equal 1 out of ...

Below is the current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];

    }

if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}
else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    ++$_SESSION['sessionCount'];
}


$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

UPDATE:

Below was a previous attempt which did not work as it keep stating 2 OF 4 or 2 OF 5 or 2 OF 2 and etc:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 0;

    }

else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}


$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

Comment: I think you're missing something here (or I am)... the user will only have 1 session (until you invalidate/timeout/destroy it) - they can't have multiple sessions (unless they are using separate browsers)

Comment: what is the value of `$_POST['sessionNum']`?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dFQzAV)?

Comment: @orzechowskid it is the same number as the number after the OF ... So if it is 1 OF 5, then $_POST['sessionNum]' is 5, if it is 2 OF 3, then $_POST['sessionNum]' is 3.

Comment: @DaveRandom The problem I have is lets say I am on session 2 of 3, and then I go back to a previous page by clicking on the "Back" button on the browser menu, and then create a new number of sessions (lets say 5) and submit, then instead of the line saying 1 OF 5, it is still saying 2 OF 5, any ideas why this is? I have stated that I wanted the sessionCount to be 1 if !isset.

Comment: That is because after the first session initialization, the counter is always set (so `!isset` will only be true the first time). I think you need to remove your second `if` block and move the `$_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;` line inside the first `if` block.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have tried your idea from your comment but it is still display 2 out of 4 Sessions or 2 out of 3 Sessions etc. I have included updated code at bottom of question to see what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
++$_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

with this

```
$_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
```

---

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
    //Declare my counter for the first time
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
}

if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}
```

Comment: This counts up the session which is cool but lets say I am on session 2 of 3, and then I go back to a previous page by clicking on the "Back" button on the browser menu, and then create a new number of sessions (lets say 5) and submit, then instead of the line saying 1 OF 5, it is still saying 2 OF 5, any ideas why this is?

Comment: Then, every time you change the session limit reset the session count. $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 0;